# How to prefer LAN range IPv6 addresses?

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, ipv6

My router assigns each device two IPv6 addresses, one global from the 2001::/16 range and a local address from fd00::/16 and resolves hostnames to these IPs, i.e., a globally routable IPv6, a private IPv6, and a local IPv4 (with the usual NAT routing).

When I now use ping or ssh, they use the global address, but I would like them to prefer the local address. Is there a way to define which ranges are preferred, when multiple ranges are available?

EDIT:

I do not care about what the IPs actually look like. The router provides two subnets and DNS and it is working as expected with SLAAC. A hostname has two AAAA records and programs seem to select the record with the global address on one machine and the record with the local address on another machine.

I want them to use the local on both machines and in addition it would be nice to know if there are mechanisms to configure this in detail.
But for a start, a "prefer local" solution would be sufficient.

Comment: When you say they are using global addresses, where are they getting them from? Are you using hostnames?

Comment: The Global address range is actually `2000::/3`, and the locally assignable ULA range is `fd00::/8`, but [the next 40 bits _must_ be randomly chosen](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4193#section-3.2.1), giving you a 48-bit prefix with a high degree of uniqueness that gives you 65,536 different `/64` networks to use locally.

Comment: @hardillb I am getting global and local addresses from a Fritzbox router. Debian computers seem to prefer the private range or at least try it as well, but a new Gentoo installation tries the global address (and fails for firewall reasons, which are beyond the scope of the question).

Comment: That still doesn't explain how you are actually getting hold of the addresses. Edit the question to include an example of `ping` to show how the address is being used in context

Comment: The Fritzbox acts as IPv6 router and distributes two networks via SLAAC. You can configure which combinations of private and public ranges you want and I let it distribute both. The router works as expected, the selection from multiple AAAA records works differently. There is no need to include `ping`, it just selects the same IP as the other programs.

Comment: "_a private IPv6_" IPv6 does not have Private addressing the way IPv4 does. There is ULA addressing, but, unlike IPv4 Private addressing, it assumed to have a high degree of uniqueness, where IPv4 Private addressing is expected to be used in many, many different networks.  "_a local IPv4 (with the usual NAT routing)._" NAT and routing are two very different things, and you should not confuse them. Routing forwards packets based on the destination IP address, while NAT is simply replacing either or both the source or destination addresses. One does not depend on the other.

Comment: "_I would like them to prefer the local address._" Which local? Every IPv6 interface will have a Link-Local address, but it can only be used on that link. You could assign Unique Local Addressing, and it can be used on your local network, but not on the public Internet.

Comment: OK, so we've moved this forward and this is actually a question about DNS resolution. Are you using the `.local` domain to resolve the addresses (this is why I wanted to see the ping command in context)

Comment: You make it more complicated than neccessary. I have a router. This router provides SLAAC and DNS. For the address `pc.fritz.box`, I get one IPv4, one fd/7 and one globally routable IPv6 address. Programs prefer the globally routable address, but for firewall reasons (which are out of scope here) I would like them to use the fd/7 address. In my use case it does not matter how the IPs are formed (it is just the usual SLAAC algorithm), it matters which one is selected when a hostname has multiple `AAAA` records.

Comment: Before you start argumenting: Yes, `.box` is a valid TLD now. You can argument with Fritz! about changing their LAN domain to `fritz.local` or something like this. Their choice may be unfortunate, but it is not part of the problem.

Comment: The reason I wanted to know if you were using `.local` addresses is because the name resolution clould have been done via mDNS/Avahi on the old box, which would have returned the link local (fd/7) addresses. So now we know this is about preferences in selecting an address from a DNS response which VERY MUCH wasn't clear from the original question.

Comment: @hardlib Okay, now I understand. The resolution is done using the DNS server of a consumer router (plastic box with wifi), which also does DHCP and SLAAC. The IPs and DNS are correct and my problem is about different Linux distributions choosing different IPs (v6) from the DNS entry.

Answer (score 3):

*[RFC 6724, Default Address Selection for Internet Protocol Version 6 (IPv6)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6724)*, regarding address selection, says that is expected:

> By default, global IPv6 destinations are preferred over ULA
> destinations, since an arbitrary ULA is not necessarily reachable

Assuming the prefix somewhere in 2001::/16 is yours, it is local. Packets bounce off the local routers and back through the LAN, not touching the internet.  If on link, direct to the destination, not even hitting a router.  This can seem foreign compared to IPv4 where addresses are so scarce, few can afford to address a LAN with public addresses.

While it is possible to adjust the selection policies, do not bother. You have perfectly usable addresses that happen to be globally routable. If your ISP didn't give you a (static) prefix, ULA would be more appealing.

Comment: My question is not about which range to use, but about how to change which addresses are preferred.

Comment: @allo, you did not read the RFC where it explains how to do that: "_However, a site-specific policy entry can be used to cause ULAs within a site to be preferred over global addresses as follows._"

Comment: Sorry, but I do not want to start reading RFCs to use IPv6 on my desktop computer. I just want a solution how to configure Linux to prefer one AAAA record over the other. Knowing that one distribution already does this, but now knowing how to configure it myself. This can't be that hard.

Comment: Assuming glibc, `man gai.conf` tells you *how* to adjust `getaddrinfo()` behavior, but *why* is left to the RFCs. I didn't mention this in my answer because I don't see what the problem is, why is ULA better?  You can route and firewall your global routable prefixes as "local" security zones if desired.

Comment: My guess is that he is in Germany where all the ISPs change everyone's global IPv6 prefix on a regular basis (read: daily or even more frequently) on residential connections. For "privacy".

Comment: @MichaelHampton Yes. And I like it for privacy reasons, but in the LAN I obviously like to have "static" addresses.